# ¿Cómo solucionar base de datos de solo lectura en mi instalador de mi proyecto? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

Terminé de elaborar mi proyecto y me funciona correctamente, **se registrar datos y todo lo demás(solo cuando lo ejecuto del mismo Visual Studio)** y cuando genero su **instalador** con el **visual studio 2017**, todo se ejecuta correctamente; pero cuando inicio mi programa y trato de **registrar datos** en mi **base de datos** me sale el error de que mi base de datos **no puede actualizar** porque es de **solo lectura(read-only)**, pero en mi proyecto de instalación que genero con el visual la opción **ReadOnly** esta en **false** y también tengo el archivo de manifesto **(app.manifest)** para que se ejecute como administrador y no me genere conflictos pero de igual manera me sigue marcando el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos Extras:

1. Mi Base de datos es de manera local (.mdf).
2. Nombre de la Base de Datos DBSLEEP.
3. Visual Studio Installer (Proyecto de Instalación del propio Visual Studio) -Setup Proyect

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo.Estás haciendo consultas directamente contra un archivo .mdf en lugar de contra la instancia del sql server?

Comment: Has revisado los permisos? A ver si el usuario que estás utilizando sólo tiene permisos de lectura...

Comment: Mi usuario tiene permisos de administrador, pero de igual manera solo me genera conflicto una vez generado mi instalador pero cuando lo ejecuto del mismo visual todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: @Pikoh, mi base de datos es del propio visual para que se cree de manera local y las consultas también las hago directamente hacia la base de datos.

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\DBSleep.mdf; Integrated Security=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;"

Comment: En ese caso, tiene toda la pinta como dice @PabloSimonDiEstefano de un problema de permisos. deberías poner tu mdf en la carpeta ProgramData y apuntar tu aplicación a una ruta dentro de esa carpeta

Comment: Pero eso no afectará si el usuario desea instalar el programa en una ubicación diferente?

Comment: El usuario debe poder instalar el programa donde quiera. Pero para almacenar datos Microsoft creo específicamente la carpeta ProgramData, sobre la que las aplicaciones tienen permiso de modificación.

Comment: @Pikoh, por favor me podrías dar un ejemplo de como poder mover a la carpeta ProgramData mi base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de permisos, pone tu mdf en la carpeta programData

Comment: Una descripción un poco más detallada haría que sea una mejor respuesta. Está claro que es un tema de permisos, pero ¿por qué se da? ¿por qué lo solucionaría así? ¿cómo/cuáles serían los pasos para moverlo?